# Ubuntu: List all files that came at a specific minute of the hour

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

How to get a list of files that came at the 18th minute of the hour?

Found this but it lists all the files after a particular timestamp. I only want the files that originated in the 18th minute of the hour.

```
find . -newermt 'Feb 9'
```

Comment: `find` supports `-mmin` to filter by relative time. I don't know if it'll do absolute time easily. `ls -l | grep` ?

Comment: you'll have to define what you mean by `originated`. Are you talking about a file that is so big that it took more than 1 minute to create? Good luck.

Comment: Indeed, what do you mean by "came at" and "originated"?  Most likely, your file system records atime (the time the file was last accessed), ctime, (the time the meta data for the file was last changed), and mtime (the time the file was last modified).  Which one is relevant to your query?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are looking for the 18th minute of a *specific* hour (let's say the 12th hour), you can do it like this:

```sh
find . -newermt "Feb 9 12:17:59" -not -newermt "Feb 9 12:19:00"
```

Assuming you are looking for the 18th minute of *any* hour on that day, you can do it like this:

```sh
find . -newermt "Feb 9" -not -newermt "Feb 10" -print0 |xargs -0 \
  ls -ld --full-time |awk -F : '$2 == 18'
```

(`ls --full-time` is a GNU extension, but you said that you're on Ubuntu, so it is supported for you.  If your desired time is within the last few months, you're fine without that flag (so long as `ls` doesn't replace the time with the year).  Similarly, `find -newermt` is only available in GNU and BSD implementations.  Otherwise, you might have to calculate the minutes and use `-mmin`.)

I am also assuming that `-newermt` is the type of timing that you are looking for.  As noted in the comments to the question, your usage of `originated` is unclear.  `-newermt` will search by modification time, so perhaps you want `-newerBt` for the "birth time" of the file.  Refer to the `newerXY reference` section of [`man find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) for further clarification.

---

A more portable version, without relying upon GNU or BSD extensions, although relying on `perl` to calculate the exact desired age in minutes, would be:

```sh
find . -mmin `perl -MTime::Local -we '$_ = time - timelocal(0,18,12,9,1,2015); printf "%.0f", $_ / 60'`
```

That syntax of [`Time::Local::timelocal`](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/Time-Local-1.2300/lib/Time/Local.pm#timelocal%28%29_and_timegm%28%29) is `timelocal(sec,min,hour,day,month-1,year)`.  Note that months are one off, so Feb is `1` because Jan is `0`.  This may have some rounding errors, so it's probably better to run the perl line on its own and then use a range with it (e.g. given perl returning 288, try `find . -mmin -287 -not -mmin -289`).